# Google App maker grouping in list view

Tags: sharepoint, google-app-maker

I have a requirement to group list view in app maker. In app maker there are three options to show data in list view.

- Using Tables
- Using List View
- Using Accordion

In that Accordion has similar functionality of grouping. But in sample projects accordion is used to show details for a base record. But I need **grouping** like how it is available in **SharePoint**.

Can we group data like **SharePoint**.

Comment: Your question is targeted to people who know both SharePoint and App Maker, I don't think that there are lots of them at this time... Can you explain, what you want to do without referencing SharePoint?

Comment: Okay, I want to group data in list view. App maker has accordion option but it is not working properly to my requirement.